# How do you debug a Go binary that takes input file redirection and output file redirection?

Tags: go, stdout, stdin, delve

I have a [Go](https://golang.org/) binary file called "runme" that successfully runs like so:

```
./runme encrypt --password=password < plaintext.txt > encrypted.txt
```

It successfully reads in a file called "plaintext.txt" and outputs an encrypted file called "encrypted.txt".

Now I would like to use the [dlv debugger for Go](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) to debug it like so:

```
dlv exec  ./runme -- encrypt -password=password < plaintext.txt > encrypted.txt
```

However I get the following error message from the dlv debugger:

```
Stdin is not a terminal, use '-r' to specify redirects for the target process or --allow-non-terminal-interactive=true if you really want to specify a redirect for Delve
```

So I try again slightly differently:

```
dlv exec -r ./runme -- encrypt -password=password < plaintext.txt > encrypted.txt
```

But I get the exact same error message shown above.  Then I try the following:

```
dlv exec --allow-non-terminal-interactive=true  ./runme -- encrypt -password=password < plaintext.txt > encrypted.txt
```

This time I get a different error message:

```
Command failed: command not available
```

What seems like a simple thing I am not able to do in the debugger.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `So I try again slightly differently:` Really? ... Did you read the documentation about how `-r` is supposed to be used?

Comment: Use the -r flag. `dlv help redirect`

Comment: I tried 
    dlv exec -r [stdin] plaintext.txt -r [stdout] encrypted.txt ./runme -- encrypt -password=password    but it gives me the error "redirect error: stdin redirected twice"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from @tkausl and @gopher I was able to figure it out.

Solution is:

```
dlv exec -r stdin:plaintext.txt  -r stdout:encrypted.txt ./runme -- encrypt -password=password
```